# Cypress doesn't send server requests to the expected account

Tags: node.js, cookies, mocha.js, ui-automation, cypress

Cypress didn't return search data or saved search results when switching to another page that should keep and render the data as well.

When I'm executing some automated use case by cypress on my local machine for search results it should return the data but something wrong in cases that cypress is handling with data for for new screens.

The tested use cases is below:
1. heading to the main screen
2. switching to another account
3. search for valid order that existing on the DB

**Actual result by Cypress:**
The server didn't return any data, in fact I've noticed the request is sent to the default account and not to the expected one.

**Actual result outside the cypress session:**
The data returns ok for the expected account.

**The code including a pre conditions to handle the session cookies for to remember the switched account for all the requests (utils.auth_handler) -**

```
let server_auth_url = Cypress.env('server') + urls.server_auth;
cy.request('POST', server_auth_url, currentUser);
Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_id', 'remember_token');
```

**The test full case script:**

```
import * as loc from '../support/locators';
import * as urls from '../support/urls';
import * as utils from '../support/utils';
import { quick_login } from '../support/init.js';

describe('WebApp - Orders', function() {
    beforeEach(() => {
        utils.auth_handler();
    });

    before(() => {
        quick_login();
    });

    it('Orders - data loading time',function() {
        cy.visit(urls.expand_data_orders);
        cy.get(loc.switch_to_orders).click();
        cy.get(loc.graphs,{ timeout: 5000 }).should('be.visible');
        cy.get(loc.orders_table,{ timeout: 5000 }).should('be.visible');
        cy.get(loc.data_summary,{ timeout: 5000 }).should('be.visible');
    });

    it('Orders - Search data validation', function () {
        cy.get(loc.order_results_row).first().then(($id_value) => {
            // store the button's text
            let txt = $id_value.text();
            cy.log(txt);
            cy.get(loc.search_field).type(txt + '{enter}');
        })
    });
});
```

[image]

**My main question is how to handle that is use case when changing accounts and want to use the new switched account as the default for any server request / What wrong with my current code?**

Thanks.

Comment: By default, Cypress clears out the session post a test step (after every `it`). Using `Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_id', 'remember_token');` will persist the session information between the tests. Not sure, if this could fit your account switching needs.

Comment: @KondasamyJayaraman Thanks for your comment, do you have any idea what can  be alternative for this use case instead 'cookies.preserveOnce' ?

Comment: As you want to simulate multi-user tests, I would suggest you to remove the line mentioned. Cypress should automatically handle new user sessions.